# jq - find duplicates in a value which is nested array of strings

Tags: jq

Assuming the below input, how can I detect the presence of duplicates in the replicas list? (replicas":[**5,5**,6]")

```
{"version":1,
 "partitions":
   [{"topic":"mytopic1","partition":3,"replicas":[4,5],"log_dirs":["any","any"]},
    {"topic":"mytopic1","partition":1,"replicas":[5,5,6],"log_dirs":["any","any"]},
    {"topic":"mytopic2","partition":2,"replicas":[6,5],"log_dirs":["any","any"]}]
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

This one will give you an array of just the partitions with duplicates in the replicas field:

```sh
 jq '[.partitions[] | select((.replicas | length) != (.replicas | unique | length))]' input.json
```

Pretty-printed example output:

```json
[
  {
    "topic": "mytopic1",
    "partition": 1,
    "replicas": [
      5,
      5,
      6
    ],
    "log_dirs": [
      "any",
      "any"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What a great way to tackle the problem. Thank you, this will work just nicely.